# Having a checkbox inside a split button list

Tags: checkbox, jquery-mobile

My client would like to have a [split button list](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html), but instead of an image, have a checkbox.  That way, the user can check/uncheck an item, or touch the right-arrow to get more info.

The problem is:

> The default styles will set the width of the element to 100% of the
>   parent container.

Q: How can I incorporate a [checkbox](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/) into a split button list?

Answer (score 1):

This works fairly well:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
      <input checked type="checkbox" name="CollID" id="CollID217" class="custom">
      <label for="CollID217">xxx</label>
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
      <a href="#" data-inline="true">Details</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And then style it with:

```
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a { width: 85% }
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b { width: 15%; } 

.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b a { 
float:right;
}
```